# parsing json file in reactjs

Tags: json, reactjs

I want to know how to parse this json file then render it?

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  }, [...]
]
```

Comment: Is it a string or raw JSON? If it's raw JSON then store it in state and use it like you would any other data? What's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to "parse" the above JSON, it seems. I just pasted it as such and wrote the following code, and it worked. So I assume you want to figure out how to render it using React. Hope this helps...

```
const posts= [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  }
];

const Posts = ({posts})=>(
  <div className="posts">
    <h1>Posts</h1>
    {posts.map(post=> <Post post={post}/> )}
  </div>
);

const Post = ({post})=>(
  <div className="post">
    <div>{post.userId}</div>
    <div>{post.id}</div>
    <div>{post.title}</div>
    <div>{post.body}</div>
  </div>
);
```